# SOLR - Auto Suggest Phrases

Tags: solr, autosuggest

I'm using the SOLR suggester component, but I cannot work out how to stop it splitting on spaces and returning multiple suggestions for each word.

I'd like to issue a command:
http://localhost:8983/solr/suggest?q="memory leak"

and get it to search my search field (created using KeywordTokenizerFactory, rather than StandardTokenizerFactory) for the whole phrase.

I'm surely just being dumb here?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this thread:
http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/suggester-issues-td3262718.html

You may have to use a custom class like the below to get what you expect:

```
import java.util.ArrayList; 
import java.util.Collection; 
import java.util.Collections; 

import org.apache.lucene.analysis.Token; 
import org.apache.solr.spelling.QueryConverter; 

/**                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
 * Converts the query string to a Collection of Lucene tokens.                                                                                                                                                                             
 **/ 
public class SpellingQueryConverter extends QueryConverter  { 

  /**                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
   * Converts the original query string to a collection of Lucene Tokens.                                                                                                                                                                 
   * @param original the original query string                                                                                                                                                                                             
   * @return a Collection of Lucene Tokens                                                                                                                                                                                                 
   */ 
  @Override 
  public Collection<Token> convert(String original) { 
    if (original == null) {                                                                                                                                                             
      return Collections.emptyList(); 
    } 
    Collection<Token> result = new ArrayList<Token>(); 
    Token token = new Token(original, 0, original.length(), "word"); 
    result.add(token); 
    return result; 
  } 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the later solr versions (we have 4.6.1), you just need to drop the following in the solrconfig.xml:

```
<queryConverter name="queryConverter" class="org.apache.solr.spelling.SuggestQueryConverter"/>
```